# Что это за код (не md5)?

Tags: хеширование

Здравствуйте ещё раз!

Проблема: не могу понять, что за код и каким макаром его расшифровать, побывал на сайте http://www.cmd5.ru/, да на этом его расшифровать ничего не вышло, кто подскажет? Вот код я его заключу в скобки, чтоб было наглядней, вот

`7D3F02047000000000025300000B00413136313732463243373001080030352F32372F3039020800
39515A445937484303290050656E7469756D285229204475616C2D436F7265204350552020453532
3030204020322E353047487A040000`  ))

Comment: Вот и багрепорт хэшкоду на тему верстки =)

@Арсентий, где код взяли? Это может быть что угодно, склеенные sha1/512, md5, а то и все вместе.

Comment: см ниже. Это просто аски. Взял скорее всего из штрихкода или QR

Comment: Это зашифрованный видео курс

Comment: Это не штрих код, пароль нужно подобрать чтоб видео курс расшифровался, это С++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz - Кусок вашей строки.
Метод - разбиваем на пары, преобразовываем из 16ричной в десятичную и пишем символ ascii с этим номером.

```
$str = '7D3F02047000000000025300000B00413136313732463243373001080030352F32372F303902080039515A445937484303290050656E7469756D285229204475616C2D436F72652043505520204535323030204020322E353047487A040000';

$array = str_split($str,2);
foreach($array as $arr){
    print(chr(hexdec($arr)));
}
```

Comment: Вы так сами делали или где такому учат?)

Comment: Наверно где-то учат. =)  
Но в данном случае сам. Обратил внимание на длину и слишком регулярную структуру(маловероятно, что такая у хэша будет). Решил проверить. Получилось.  
В детстве с батей много хексов правили. )

Comment: На каком это языке?//  
PHP. Но любой другой язык тоже с этим справится. На каком надо?

Comment: От что значит чуйка! Снимаю шляпу. Я бы из-за нулей никогда на ascii не подумал.

Comment: Ребята а как на  delphi 7  это расшифровывать пожалуйсто, хочу научиться .

Comment: http://knes.ru/uncode.php
На делфи отвечу через несколько минут: надо время, чтобы вспомнить. Или можете отправить вопрос: получится быстрее.

Comment: Я перешёл по твоей ссылке http://knes.ru/uncode.php и расшифровал первый результат ((((Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz))) это я понял а как расшифровать а это? - (((((  1F49536CFF612817971DBC5DD2CE02DF27C3508BAB50EE45AFED9B7436DE02CB24D157493BD820CC99E0CE5255ABE47066   ))))

Comment: Вопрос хороший. Для этого уже желательно иметь представление о том, что именно это за файл. Возможно, вот те два кода, которые идут слева и справа от даты - это коды шифрования. Но даже после этой операции надо будет знать изначальный формат видюшки(?). На первый взгляд, там полная белиберда, согласен. =)

Comment: @knes по Вашей ссылке получаю
>}?pSA16172F2C7005/27/09•¤E“t„02ђVзF—VТ…"’GVВФ6ч&R5RSS00 @ 2.50GHz

Comment: @knes в целом конечно - УАУ) додуть до такого )

Answer (score 1):

Просто берете и смотрите эти данные как hex. Для этого подойдет любой шестнадцатеричный редактор. Например, WinHEX.
Конкретно подстрока `Pentium(R)` - это `50656E7469756D285229`. Легко убедиться разбив последовательность на байты (по два 16-ричных символа), а затем просто найдя какому же символу соответствует эти коды в таблице ASCII. Еще там же зашифрованы скорее всего дата и серийный номер винчестера.

P.S. честно, самому смекалки мне не хватило бы, чтобы так лихо "расшифровать" эти данные.

Comment: Спасибо вам !!!!